# mount a industrial network

Tags: switching, ieee-802.11

my objective is mount a fault tolerance industrial network, in an already very populated factory.

the factory has many production lines and i want to treat them as a separate islands... so i want to put a switch(PS) in all of them(for the components of the line), and join all that switches to a central one(CS) by fiber, to avoid EMI on the factory. From that central switch join to the main switch(MS) in localCPD by another fiber.

i think this approach is fine, right?

other thing....how can i connect also by WIFI that productionLine Switches(PS). Imagine that the components of the production line are not WIFI capable, but as are connected to the PS, i think i can use some reverse AP(dont know if that exists) to connect to the WIFI in case cable broken.

how can i do that setup?

regards

Comment: We can only give you a very general description because the design is affected by many details.  If you're worried about EMI, then WiFi may not be a good option.  You should really consider hiring a professional to assess your network.

Comment: yes Ron....the physical installation of cabling will be made by a network enterprise and we try to follow they advice, but i want to have clear the general squema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fault tolerance, you'll need dual central switches with dual, redundant uplinks of the access/production switches (either using RSTP/MSTP or MC-LAG). Fiber is generally a good choice for very high EMI immunity.

For wireless connectivity you add an wireless access point (WAP) - or likely several ones. If proper coverage is required you'd need to do a wireless survey first.

Many WAPs support 'client mode' which you can use to bridge a wired client. Note that wireless networks are generally not as reliable as wired ones, especially in an electromagnetically 'noisy' environment. With a high EMI level, wireless becomes practically useless.

Comment: thanks about briged WAP....so, what do you think about WIFI MESH insustrial network? any experience?

Comment: Meshing wireless links is *much* more unreliable than deploying WAPs with wired backhaul - definitely not a recommendation.